# Installing error with e1071 package in R version 3.3.1

Tags: r, svm, r-package

I am using R 3.3.1 version and while trying to install the package "e1071" in it I get the following message:

```
install.packages("e1071")
```

> ```
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/test/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
>   C/C++/Fortran: ‘e1071’
>   These will not be installed
> ```

Looking for ways to troubleshoot and getting an accurate answer for this problem.

Comment: you can try to download the latest realse from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html and use R CMD INSATLL from command line

Comment: Which release is the best? And how what is the R command to install it?

Comment: not sure for what is the "best" but i would use the latest stable which is 1.6-7, this is not an R command, its a command line command R CMD INSTALL path-To-Package-file

Comment: Tried it shows the following error: C:\Users\test>R CMDR INSTALL C:/Users/test/Downloads/e1071_1.6-7
'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Cause your r.exe is not in you system path try to point directly to r.exe like c:\program files\r\bin\r.exe depends on where you installed R

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the following should work:

1. Download the latest binary package from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html
2. Inside R, execute the command

   ```
   install.packages(pkgs = path_to_local_file, repos = NULL)
   ```

However, if this works then the direct installation *should* also work. It’s possible that there’s no compiled version for your R version on Windows. In that case, you need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) which makes this more complicated.